# Php remove underscore if there is one and anything that comes after it

Tags: php, string, substring

I need to remove the underscore and anything that comes after it. If there is no underscore the string should be left as it is. Is is possible?

```
$str1 = 'green_apples';
$str1 = substr($str1, 0, strpos($str1, '_'));
echo $str1; // green
```

Works fine until the string contains no underscore:

```
$str2 = 'yellow';
$str2 = substr($str2, 0, strpos($str2, '_'));
echo $str2; // should be 'yellow' but nothing is printed
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
$str2 = 'yellow';
$pos = strpos($str2, '_');
$str2 = substr($str2, 0, $pos === false ? strlen($str2) : $pos);
echo $str2; // should be 'yellow' but nothing is printed
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the _ exists before substringing it like so:

```
$str2 = !(strpos($str2, '_')===false) ? substr($str2, 0, strpos($str2, '_')) : $str2;
```